# Making a simple line from a path

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm very new to Adobe Illustrator, and having problems with the pen tool.

I have a path created that is a single straight line.
*(appears as a light blue line, with anchor points at both ends, within a blue bounding box)*

This path is very precisely created exactly where I need it, relative to another object.

I have been unable to assign it "ink", so it only appears as the light blue path, but doesn't actually appear in my graphic.   I believe I need to assign a "stroke" to it, but have been unable.

In my experiments with the Pen tool, it seems paths only get a stroke / ink when they have at least 3 points, and represent a closed path.  Is this right?

If so, how can I "color" the line-segment I've created. 
(note:  precise placement is important, not just an approximate position via the mouse)

Comment: A path does not have to be closed and can be stroked with as little as 2 anchor points.  What methods have you tried to assign a stroke to it?

Comment: In the "Stroke" window, there is a setting for "Weight: 1pt.". When I change the setting to something obvious (15 pt), it affects the nearby object, but not the blue line-segment path.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @abelenky Based on your comment, it sounds like 1 of 2 things happened: 1)you accidently selected the nearby object or 2)you created the line segment as a "part" of the nearby object, effectively creating a group.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that your line segment is not attached to any other object:

1. Use your **Selection Tool** *(V)* to deselect all elements *(click in a blank area)*
2. Next, using the **Selection Tool** *(V)* again, click once on the path
3. Go to **Object > Ungroup** *(Shift + ctrl/cmd + G)*, if it's already gray-ed out, move to next step
4. Now at the top of your screen, your menu should change to the **Path** options:

   - you now have the choice of selecting a stroke color (2) or selecting a stroke size (1), either way it will create a stroke w/ color on the path.
     [image]

If after doing this, you still aren't getting a color on the path, I *suggest* you delete the path, make sure you have deselected all objects *(Step 1)* and redraw your path, **but** this time, make sure you have selected a **Stroke Color** *(see #1 on image)* ***first***.

You can always use reselect the path with the **Selection Tool** *(V)* and then use your arrow keys to move the path into place.

Good luck!

Comment: It may also be worthwhile to right-click the path and see if `Release compound shape` is an option. If it is, the path may be "grouped" without being an actual Group

Comment: True. Didn't think about that.